# Loading images to custom listview - how to gradually load?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom `Listview` - which contains an imageView, text and a checkbox.

I am loading images from dropbox (taking the thumnails or else getting the shared URL to the image) and I am loading them into the custom Listview using an `ImageAdapter`.

It is very slow to load the images in a given folder.  It takes several seconds just to load a few images, up to a minute if there are dozens, and my app crashes with I assume an Out of Memory exception if there are lots of images.

It seems to be taking about 2 seconds to get the URL from dropbox (or get the Bitmap if you decode the stream).  So it is taking 60 seconds to retreive 30 image URLs.  This is very excessive (not sure why it is taking so long?)

I am hoping I can improve my code to be a lot faster.  I would like to load the images incrementally, i.e. keep the UI responsive and load the images in batches.

I am already using an Async task, so hopefully someone can advise.

Note that I have tried using Universal Image Loader and it still takes a long time to load the images.

I should note that I think the problem is in retrieving the image data from dropbox.  The code below retrieves the thumbnail file, and is very slow.  I have tried changing the code to instead retrieve the URL link to the image, but again it is very slow to execute and loop.

**So is there any way inside of the Loop to get the images**, **to start displaying the data in the ListView, before the loop has completed?**  That is - don't wait until the `OnTaskCompleted` - but rather start displaying the images inside of the `doInBackground`?

Here is the `doInBackground` of the Async Task:

```
 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(DbxFileSystem... params) {
        //Opens thumbnails for each image contained in the dropbox folder
        try {
            DbxFileSystem fileSystem = params[0];


            for (DbxFileInfo fileInfo: fileSystem.listFolder(currentPath)) {
                DbxFile file;

//this code below is very slow to execute
                try{
                    if(fileInfo.thumbExists) // if it has a thumbnail then retrieve it
                    {
                        file = fileSystem.openThumbnail(fileInfo.path, ThumbSize.XS, ThumbFormat.PNG);
                        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(file.getReadStream());
                        pix.add(image);  // image to display in the custom listview
                        paths.add(fileInfo.path); // path to display in the custom listview

                        file.close();                     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //must be a folder if it has no thumb, so add local drawable folder icon
                        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dbfolder);
                        pix.add(image);
                        paths.add(fileInfo.path);                   

                    }
                }catch (DbxException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.gc();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return false;
        } finally {
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Then in the onTaskCompleted is where we set the Image Adapter:

```
       public void onTaskCompleted(int requestID, ArrayList<Bitmap> urls, ArrayList<DbxPath> path) {

            lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstView);
            this.paths = path;

            ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, urls, paths);
            lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is the getView of the `ImageAdapter.java`:

```
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;


        gridView = new View(context);

        // inflate image_helper layout
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        // set images
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_image);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));

        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.filename);

           textView.setText(folderName.get(position).toString());

        return gridView;
    }
```

Comment: try this library  https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Yeah I have tried that and passed in the URLS.  But the problem is my Custom ListView doesnt start populating until several seconds have passed or more.

Comment: obvious it will show the images after they get downloaded.

Comment: I know but how to gradually show the images, e.g. after 2 have downloaded then show them, and continue to download the others in the background.  I don't want to wait until they have all downloaded until they are displayed

Comment: the library i have mentioned above does exactly what you just said. have you tried it. its show the very first image which downloaded and continue downloading images in background.

Comment: Yes I have tried it - it does download the images gradually.  But it seems I have to wait until my array of URLS is complete before sending to the Image Adapter.  If there are 100 images it takes a long time to get the Array.  Anyway to start displaying before the Array of URLs is completed?

Comment: do you know if UNiversal image loader is downloading full size images?> I only want it to download a tiny image, can you force it to decrease the image size significantly??

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use Universal Image loader jar `universal-image-loader-1.9.2-SNAPSHOT-with-sources.jar`

Then adapter is like this

```
public class LinkAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MediaModel>{

    ArrayList<MediaModel> medias;
    Activity context;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    DisplayImageOptions options;

    public LinkAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<MediaModel> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.medias = objects;
        this.context = context;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher).cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true).considerExifParams(true)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        ImageView iconImage;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.link_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_row_title);
            holder.description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_row_description);
            holder.iconImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_row_icon);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(medias.get(position).mediaTitle);
        holder.description.setText(medias.get(position).mediaInfo);
        imageLoader.displayImage(medias.get(position).mediaThumbImgUrl, holder.iconImage,options);

        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have already tried this type of approach, but it is the loop where I get the images (or URLS is using image loader) that I want to speed up. see the main thread